# QuickStart zend

Tags: zend-framework

I was following quickstart tutorial. My servername is "quickstart.local" which works fine but  when i click guestbook then the link "quickstart.local/guestbook" doesn't work and message "An error occurred Application error" is displayed. 
Any idea? Tried to find answers hard but to no avail.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1` (in your config) if you don't have logging enabled and you should see the exception details. You could always modify the ErrorHandler (default: application/controllers/ErrorController.php) so that you get the error details emailed to you, etc.

If you are using Zend Studio / Eclipse, then you could try using the debugger if available.

Comment: Thanks! I did that and could read the error detail on the page. It was due to mysql connection. I checked quickstart.local/guestbook/sign and it did work.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the .htaccess file is misconfigurated or the Apache won't handle the .htaccess the way it should. Does http://quickstart.local/index.php/guestbook work? In case yes: mod_rewrite module on your server does not work correctly.

Comment: Thanks.I tried that link but it doesn't work. I checked the php info mode_rewrite is in loaded modules. Any idea?

Comment: What is the result of the link? Again "An error occured" or any other error message? See the answer of @Cez to gain a more specific error message.